# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.data')]

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I have a very simple Fetch API call as part of a React Native project.  I'm seemingly able to receive the response data (verified with `Console.log()`), but for some reason, my data isn't being transferred into `useState()` properly.  I haven't had any difficulties doing this before.

This is where I'm trying to store my data:

```
const [data, setData] = useState("");
```

And this is my API call:

```
fetch('https://api.panodime.com/v1/oauth-login?email=' + email + '&token=' + token, {
    headers: { 'X-ApiKey': 'doxy08E9SqxTvgvFpB3yOEGCO4YE77m88iSXTQ5TZrcpf3Qw' }
})
    .then((response) => { return response.json() })
    .then((response) => { console.log(response.data.authToken)})
    .then((response) => setData(response.data.authToken))
    //.then(() => console.log(data))
    //.then(() => storeData(data))
    //.catch((error) => console.error(error))
```

The test data I'm using for the input parameters to the fetch API call are `email: hannah89orpington@gmail.com` and `token: 235906121209210`.

The strangest thing is that the line `.then((response) => { console.log(response.data.authToken)})` returns the authToken that I want successfully, but when I call it in `.then((response) => setData(response.data.authToken))`, it says that it's undefined.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short lesson for Promise and Thenables.

If you want to have multiple thenables like this, you need to ensure you return the value, so it can be pass on to the next function.

e.g.

```
.then((response) => { 
     console.log(response.data.authToken)
     return response //this pass response to next function
 })
.then((response) => setData(response.data.authToken))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `extra then` in response. Try this

```
fetch('https://api.panodime.com/v1/oauth-login?email=' + email + '&token=' + token, {
                headers: { 'X-ApiKey': 'doxy08E9SqxTvgvFpB3yOEGCO4YE77m88iSXTQ5TZrcpf3Qw' }
            })
     .then((response) => { return response.json() })
     .then((response) => { 
      console.log(response.data.authToken);
      setData(response.data.authToken) // do here
     })
     .then((response) => setData(response.data.authToken)) // remove this
```